# Javascript function with 2 argument holder

Tags: typescript, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to convert this `Redux` actions into `Vuex`, 
I noticed that the actions has `2 holders(I don't know the term)` for argument. 
To give an example, it looks like this:

```
export const priceAction = (amount)//first holder => async (dispatch, getState)//second holder => { ... }
```

Now in my vue, I'm trying to modularize the vuex, like this:

What the `Price` module looks like:

```
store/module/Price
/ actions.ts
/ index.ts
```

In the `Price/actions.ts`

```
export const priceAction = (amount: number) => async ({commit, dispatch}: ActionContext<State, RootStateType>, state: State) => { ... }
```

In the `Price/index.ts`

```
import * as actions from './actions'
import { state } from './state-type'
 
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: state,
    getters: {},
    mutations: {},
    actions: actions
}
```

Now, in the root reducer `store.ts`

```
import Price from './module/Price'
export const store = createStore({
    modules: {
        Price //-> This one gives me a series of errors
    }
})
```

The errors:

```
- Types of property 'actions' are incompatible.
- Type 'typeof import("D:/workspaces/proj/myproj/src/store/modules/Price/actions")' is not assignable to type 'ActionTree<any, { mainStore: string; }>'.
- Property 'priceAction ' is incompatible with index signature.
- Types of parameters 'amount' and 'injectee' are incompatible.
```

Answer (score 0):

your `action.ts` is not correct, you should export something like this from it

```
export const actions: ActionTree<PriceState, RootState> = {
    myAction({ commit }) {
        // ... some code here
        commit('myMutation', data)
    },

}
```

For a bettter understanding of this I highly recommend you this article :
https://codeburst.io/vuex-and-typescript-3427ba78cfa8

I'm using this in my projects and it works well